# Proving Hawkes intensity has all the moments.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, point-processes

Let $N_t$ be a point process whose intensity follows [Hawkes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkes_process):
\begin{align*}
  \lambda_t = \mu_t + \phi * dN_t,
\end{align*}
where $*$ is a convolution opeartor, $\phi * dN_t = \int_0^t \phi(t-s)dN_s$, and $\mu_t$ is some bounded process which has all the moments,
The question is

> **Question**. For all $k\ge0$, $\mathbb{E} [\lambda_t^k] < \infty$?

My intuition says "yes", but I have no idea how to prove it mathematically because it includes some tricky recursive relation:

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E} [\lambda_t^k] &\le C\mathbb{E}[\mu_t^k] + C\mathbb{E}[(\phi * dN_t)^k]  \\
& C\mathbb{E}[\mu_t^k] + C\int_0^t \int_{t_1}^t \cdots \int_{t_{k-1}}^t \phi(t-t_1)\cdots \phi(t-t_k) \mathbb{E} [dN_{t_1} \cdots dN_{t_k} ]
\end{align*}

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please explain your notation in more detail. What is $\mu_t$ ? If I read in Wikipedia that this is the intensity of $N_t$ why do you write $\mathbb E[\mu_t^k]$ ?

Comment: $\mu_t = \mu(t)$ is the intensity of the underlying inhomogeneous Poisson process. The subscript notation $_t$ just for simplicity, does not have a special meaning. Notice that it is not the intensity of the point process $N_t$ itself. For $\mathbb{E}[\mu_t^k]$, it derived from the simple fact $(x+y)^k \le Cx^k + Cy^k$.

Comment: Isn't $\mu_t$ deterministic ? Why do you write $E[\mu_t^k]$ ? Isn't $N_t$ the underlying inhomogeneous Poisson process ? Why do you say "the point process $N_t$ itself" ? The (Hawkes) point pricess itself should probably be $\lambda_t$.

Comment: I expect you may have some confusion on Hawkes process. $N_t$ itself is a counting process which is Hawkes, and $\lambda_t = \mathbb{E}_t[dN_t/dt]$ is the corresponding intensity, not the Hawkes process itself. On the other hand, yes $\mu_t$ is deterministic in this case.

Comment: You should not surprised that I am confused. You wrote "Let $\color{red}{N_t}$ be a point process whose intensity follows Hawkes: 
$$
  \lambda_t = \mu_t + \phi * d\color{red}{N_t},
$$
where $*$ is a convolution opeartor, $\phi * dN_t = \int_0^t \phi(t-s)dN_s$, and $\mu_t$ is some bounded process which has all the moments,..." 1. Is $\lambda_t$ that intensity that is Hawkes? 2. How is the Hawkes process $\color{red}{N_t}$ defined exactly if it is one? 3. Why do you now say in the comment that $\mu_t$ is deterministic when you said the contrary in the question?

Comment: I recommend that you edit the question to address these issues.

Comment: I cannot explain every detail of the point process theory or Hawkes process here. This question is presumably assumed to have prior knowledge of some point process and related statistics. I recommend you to read [this lecture](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00221.pdf) for very brief introduction, nevertheless, it would be better to read Daley-Vere Jones's textbook for more mathematical detail.

Comment: Surely you cannot. But we expect the questions to be clear.

Comment: It's possible to get explicit results, but if you want a quick solution, you can simply bound $\mathbb{E}(dN_{t_1}\cdots dN_{t_k})$ by $\mathbb{E}(dN_{t_1})=\lambda_{t_1}$. Then, since you know that last quantity has an upper bound on $[0,t_1]$ (Gronwall's inequality for instance, or Laplace transform, or whatever you may have used to bound the expectation of the intensity before), you're left with a finite bound on the RHS

Answer (score 1):

**This is for the self-reference.**

I will use the induction argument to show this.

For $k=1$, we have $\mathbb{E} \lambda_t = \mu_t + \phi * \mathbb{E} \lambda_t$, and this is in fact the Volterra integral equation. So we have its solution as $\mathbb{E} \lambda_t = \mu_t + \psi * \mu_t$, where $\psi$ is resolvent kernel which satisfies $\psi = \phi + \phi * \psi$. Hence, obviously $\mathbb{E} \lambda_t < C$.

For $k>1$, the inequality $(x+y)^k \le (1+\epsilon)^{k-1} x^k + (1+\epsilon^{-1})^{k-1}y^k$ for any $x,y,\epsilon > 0$ gives
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\lambda_t^k \le (1+\epsilon)^{k-1}\mu_t^k + (1+\epsilon^{-1})^{k-1} \mathbb{E} [ (\phi * dN_t)^k].
\end{align*}
Then by martingale representation of $N_t$, we have $dN_t = \lambda_t\, dt + dM_t$, and
\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{E} [ (\phi * dN_t)^k] \le (1+\delta)^{k-1}\mathbb{E} [ (\phi * \lambda_t)^k] + (1+\delta^{-1})^{k-1} \mathbb{E} [ (\phi * dM_t)^k]
\end{align*}
To bound the first term, we apply Hölder's inequality $(\int \phi \lambda)^k \le (\int \phi \lambda^k)(\int \phi)^{k-1}$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} [ (\phi * \lambda_t)^k] &\le \mathbb{E} [\phi * \lambda^k_t] \bigg( \int_0^t \phi(t-s)\,ds\bigg)^{k-1} \\
&\le \| \phi \|_1^k \mathbb{E} \lambda_t^k.
\end{align*}
For the second term, by Lemma 2.1.5 in [Jacod and Protter's book (2012)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-24127-7), we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} [ (\phi * dM_t)^k] &\le C \mathbb{E} [ \phi^k * \lambda_t] + C\mathbb{E}\big[ (\phi^2 * \lambda_t)^{\frac{k}{2}} \big] \\
&\le C \|\phi\|_k^k \mathbb{E} \lambda_t + C\mathbb{E}[\phi*\lambda^{\frac{k}{2}}_t] \bigg( \ \int_0^t \phi(t-s) ds \bigg)^{\frac{k}{2} - 1} \\
&\le C \|\phi\|_1^k C + C \|\phi\|_1 \mathbb{E}\lambda_t^{\frac{k}{2}} \|\phi\|_1^{\frac{k}{2}-1}
\end{align*}
and this is bound because all the previous value is bounded.
By combining all of these, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \lambda_t^k &\le (1+\epsilon)^{k-1}\mu_t^k + (1+\epsilon^{-1})^{k-1} \mathbb{E} [ (\phi * dN_t)^k] \\
&\le C_{\epsilon} + (1+\epsilon^{-1})^{k-1}(1+\delta)^{k-1}\|\phi\|_1^k \mathbb{E} \lambda_t^k + C_{\epsilon,\delta}.
\end{align*}
Thus, by choosing $\epsilon,\delta$ sufficiently small or large that makes
$$
(1+\epsilon^{-1})^{k-1}(1+\delta)^{k-1}\|\phi\|_1^k < 1,
$$
we have the result.